# How do I get LEDs to turn on according to a continuous Python input?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, led, communication, python

I'm trying to make a tuner. 3 LEDs are connected to the Arduino board, each one corresponding to one situation (too high, low or correct).

Python handles the detecting of a note according to the mic input, and determines which led should be turned on, but as it's a live tuner, Python sends the information pretty fast.

I've figured out how to turn a led on one at a time and keep it on as long as the input doesn't change, but it only works at a low speed when I do it manually, with a Python program like this :

```
code=1
while code!=0:
    code=input("Code?")
    ser.write(code.encode('utf-8'))
```

If I try it with a Python code such as :

```
code= '5'
while 1:
ser.write(code.encode('utf-8'))
```

then the LEDs just stay off.

Here is my Arduino Code :

```
int hauteur = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode (2, OUTPUT); //red pin
    pinMode (6, OUTPUT); //green pin
    pinMode (5, OUTPUT); //yellow pin
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if(Serial.available ()) {
        hauteur = Serial.parseInt();

        while (hauteur==2) {
            (digitalWrite(2,HIGH));
            if (Serial.available ()) { hauteur=Serial.parseInt(); }
        }
        digitalWrite(2,LOW);

        while (hauteur==5){
            (digitalWrite(5,HIGH));
            if (Serial.available ()) { hauteur=Serial.parseInt(); }
        }
        digitalWrite(5,LOW);

        while (hauteur==6){
            (digitalWrite(6,HIGH));
            if (Serial.available ()) { hauteur=Serial.parseInt(); }
        }
        digitalWrite(6,LOW);

        Serial.flush();
    }
}
```

If 2, 5 or 6 are received with enough time in between them, then the board does what it's supposed to do and turns on the according LED. How can I reduce that necessary lapse of time to get a real time change of lights like a live tuner?

Comment: Try to not send only the number, but also a trailing non-digit character as a delimiter (like "\n" the newline character)

Comment: what for is the Serial.flush()? you don't output anything on Serial in loop()

Comment: make two variables. current pin and next pin. read value in next pin and do nothing if next pin is same as current pin. if they are different set next pin high, current pin low and set current pin to next pin value.

Comment: your arduino code is very badly formatted, and therefore hard to read .... please correct the indentation ......... your second python snippet is also badly indented and it will not work as expected

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parseInt for one digit. Use Serial.read().

```
  hauteur = Serial.read() - 48; // 48 is ascii code of '0'
```

or better send bytes from python, not digit characters